# Question regarding the multiplicity of eigenvalues of a matrix polynomial .

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ If $\operatorname p(x)$ is a polynomial over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F[x]$ and let $A$ be an $n×n$ square matrix, then it is known that every eigenvalue of $\operatorname p(A)$ is of the form $\operatorname {p(\lambda)}$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ .

If the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ be known, what can be inferred about that of $\operatorname p(\lambda) ?$
Can something interesting be told about the eigenvectors of $\operatorname p(A)$ knowing that of $A$ ???

$\mathbf {My \ approach}$ : I tried some examples and the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of $\operatorname p(A)$ turned out to be equal respectively to that of $A$ , so I tried to prove $\operatorname {det(xI-A) = det(xI- \operatorname p(A))}$ , but I couldn't and I'm not sure whether this is true or not .

$\mathbf {Bonus} :$ If $\operatorname p(A)$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb F[x]$, can anything be said about diagonalizability of that of $A$ ???

Comment: To answer this question in general it suffices to reduce to the case where $A$ is a Jordan block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting statement must be that since $\Bbb F$ is a closed field all the matrices are triangolable, so for every matrix $A$ it exists a basis such that in that coordinates $A$ is a triangolar matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal, counted with algebraic multiplicity.

Then when we evaluate a polinomial $p$ in a matrix $A=[a]_{ij}$ we obtain that $p(A)=[b]_{ij}$ is so that $\forall i\;\; [b]_{ii}=p([a]_{ii})$ (you can easily prove this property demonstrating it for simple powers by induction and concluding by linearity). So you see that for all $\lambda$ eigen value of $A$ then $p(\lambda)$ is eigen value of $p(A)$.

But nothing can be concluded about the multiplicities without knowing more informations on $p$: for example thanks to Hamilton-Cayley Theorem we know that if $q$ is the characteristic polinomial of $A$ then $q(A)=0$, while if $f$ is a polinomial so that $f(\lambda)\ne f(\mu)$ for all $\lambda, \mu$ different eigen values of $A$, then algebraic multiplicity of $f(\lambda)$ for $f(A)$ is the same of $\lambda$ for $A$.

About the bonus question the answer is the same: in general $A$ has not to be diagonalizable, infact for every $A$ not diagonal $q(A)=0$ that is diagonal ($q$ is always the characteristic polinomial of $A$).
I hope I answered your question, maybe if you have more details I will be happy to approach them with you!

Comment: Sir, "$f(\lambda)\ne f(\mu)$ for all $\lambda, \mu$ different eigen values of $A$, then algebraic multiplicity of $f(\lambda)$ for $f(A)$ is the same of $\lambda$ for $A$" - is it by triangularization ???

Comment: Yes, sure. You can see this by drawing a generic Matrix @RabiKumarChakraborty